# Why don't Pokemon appear unless I restart my Pokemon Go app?

Tags: pokemon-go

I go out searching for Pokemon with my brother and when a Pokemon appears, it would show on his device but not on mine. So then I close the Pokemon Go app and start it up again, and then the Pokemon appears.  Why is this? Is there any fix?
I have a Samsung Galaxy s6 edge, and the main problem with this, is that after restarting the app many times, it seems that I get a softban so I cannot use my account for around 1 hour or so.

Comment: Is your phone rooted or do you have developer options enabled? I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling the app incase its just an app glitch.

Comment: I suspect that you may simply be getting disconnected form the server or have a bad connection. Can you collect from / interact properly with Pokestops when the Pokemon aren't showing up? I have had a similar problem and simply restarting the app seems to re-establish the server connection, but I have never had any type of soft ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the offical reddit site:

> **I can't see Pokémon but my friends can? (OR) I can't connect but my
> friends can?**
>
> Servers are very unstable at the moment. Some players can
> connect while others can't. Check your time and date settings to make
> sure they are correct (you may have to toggle time settings to
> Automatic syncing). This also might be a compatibility issue with
> certain phones or services having better connection than others. There
> is nothing you can do at the moment. (see support below)

https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t5pfd/server_status_and_known_issues_faq/